# Get current IP from adapter name?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I need to get the current IP from a adapter by name, I know how to find out the information about that given adapter but not if that can be used to get the IP of that adapter:

```
foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in networks)
{
    if (adapter.Name == "DataServer")
        break;
}
```

The adapater is named "DataServer" now I would like to know if there is a way to use that information to grab the actual IP address that adapter is assiged with without using the internet and with a way that I can assure it is connected to the given adapter name.

Or if there is a different way of doing this where I can get the IP by adapter name.

Comment: @SLaks does that matter in this case ? the ip is external but its not the only interface that have an external IP.

Comment: You cannot get the external IP without an external server to tell it to you.

Comment: Well I still can't see how that is relevant to the question, but this server currently have 3 network cards where 2 have External IP's and yes they are given by external server and 1 network card gets an internal IP given by a internal dhcp server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call

```
adapter.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses.Single(a => a.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).Address
```